# Publish the Column which has Missing Values - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have source table with details about employees, i need to derive an Missing information table. with list of Missing values. The missing values may be NULL or JUST empty Spaces.

```
Source Table
**************

Name    Age       Gender     Experience 
-------------------------------------------------------------
David   22         M           IT
John    [NULL]     M          POLITICS
Judy    19      [NULL]        [NULL]
Jasmine [NULL]  [NULL]        [NULL]


Target Table
**************

Name    Missing_description
---------------------------------------------
John    Missing Age
Judy    Missing Gender, Experience
Jasmine Missing Age, Gender, Experience
```

Comment: Hints: You will need "INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM". The insert will have to be conditional to generate the "missing_description" using CASE/DECODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
insert into TargetTable (name, description)
select name,'Missing'||description from (
select name, LISTAGG(descr, ', ') within group (order by descr) as description
from (
 select name, 'age,' as descr from SourceTable where age is null
 union all
 select name, 'Gener,' from SourceTable where gender is null
 union all
 select name, 'Experience' from SourceTable where Experience  is null    
) as a
group by name) as b
```

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Comment: its throwing me an error message "00933" sql statement not ended properly near the UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Writing by memory, havent oracle installed right now, but query can be something like this:

```
insert into TargetTable (name, description)
select name, LISTAGG(descr, ', ') within group (order by descr) as description
from (
 select name, 'Missing age' as descr from SourceTable where age is null
 union all
 select name, 'Missing Gener' from SourceTable where gender is null
 union all
 ...
) as a
group by name
```

String aggregation is taken from [String Aggregation Techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)